# what is a good way to stop a thread in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to passthrough the  input obtained from the microphone to the speaker (the goal is to be able to perform audio processing in real time in the future). This is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;  // 1024 ORIGINAL
    final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    int i= 0;
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            recordAndPlay();
        }
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        init();
        newThread = new MyThread();
        newThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void recordAndPlay() {
        short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
        int num = 0;
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        record.startRecording();
        track.play();
        while (true) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
            for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }

    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        else{
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }

/*
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        newThread.stop();
    }
    */

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
}
```

Brief overview:
The `while(true) {}` infinite loop in `recordAndPlay()` function continuously reads raw audio samples from the microphone and outputs the raw samples to the speaker. `recordAndPlay()` is called from a Thread started in the `onCreate()` function. So it starts sending the input on the microphone to the speaker as soon as the program starts (well actually after a few seconds lag but I think this latency in unavoidable). I also have a button that can pause and resume this pass through. Now if the Thread is not stopped, the pass through continues even when I exit the application or the application looses focus (so even when the phone is on the desktop it keeps doing the passthrough).

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    newThread.stop();
}
```

This code causes the app to crash on exit (**Why?**) so I used

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

that I found somewhere in stackoverflow (I forgot where). It seems to do what I want for now, but I want know if this is the proper way to stop the Thread or not. It does what I need, that is, it stops the passthrough when I exit the application, but I am not sure what exactly the killProcess() function does to my application overall, and if it is the best way to stop a Thread that I started myself.

Also, I can get the same effect if I exit my application (or loose focus to it) while the passthrough is being paused. But I assume this means the Thread is still running which means the infinite loop is also continuously running as well. Is it a good idea to do this, that is, just leave the Thread running, as long as my overall program is behaving as I want it to? What if I have lots of Threads or other background processes running? Can this practice cause memory problems in the future if the app grows too big?

Answer (score 4):

Threads should periodically check for some `shouldTerminate` flag in their loop, then just set this flag from UI thread and (optionally) wait until thread terminate gracefully. Don't forget `volatile` or proper field synchronization.

Comment: what determines which state this flag is in? So I somehow program in the flag inside the infinite while loop; how would I close the thread?

Comment: Why use an additional boolean flag when the language already provides one: `Thread.current thread().isInterrupted()`, which can be set with `thread.interrupt()`?

Answer (score 1):

Please remember to call `super.onDestroy` after releasing your memory or finishing the thread. Otherwise it will throw `Exception`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // You code here to finish the thread
    super.onDestroy(); // Please call THIS too
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Thread class to something like this:

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    private volatile boolean finished = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!finished) {
            // do stuff on thread
        }

    }

    public void stopThread() {
        finished = true;
    }

}
```

In your onDestroy method call stopThread().

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    newThread.stopThread();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If you wish, you can also wait for thread to stop, by using this method:

```
    private void joinThread(Thread thread) {
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // to be handled as you wish
            }
        }
    }
```

Put this method in your activity and call it after `newThread.stopThread()`.

Comment: so do you think I should bring the code inside `recordandplay()` function into the `run()` function itself? Again, if I press the home button and loose focus on the application, it's still the same thing, that is, the passthrough keeps occuring even if the phone is on the desktop. Is there a way I can pause a running thread?

Comment: You can still call recordAndPlay() from inside of Thread.run() method, there is no need to change that. To handle situation you've described, you need to override onPause and onResume activity methods. Most basic solution is to stop thread on pause and start a new thread on resume.

Comment: so if the `Thread.run()` function exits, is that equivalent to the Thread stopping? Because I just realised that in my program the `run()` function never exits, where as your suggestion basically makes sure that the run function will exit at some point.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a provided flag for interuption.
 Correct your while loop to the following.
 And just call interupt(); in onDestroy or wherever.

```
private class thrd extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            //TODO
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    thrd.interupt();
}
```