# Does a Thread remember it's state the next time the same application is run?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass through the audio sample obtained at the microphone to the speaker
This is the code I am using, using the [suggestions I obtained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326262/what-is-a-good-way-to-stop-a-thread-in-android/)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;  // 1024 ORIGINAL
    final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    int i= 0;
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private boolean passThroughMode = true;
        /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            recordAndPlay(passThroughMode);
        }
        */

        MyThread(){
            super();
        }

        MyThread(boolean newPTV){
            this.passThroughMode = newPTV;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
            short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            int num = 0;
            // am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            // am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            // while (passThroughMode) {
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                    lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
                track.write(lin, 0, num);
            }
        }
        /*
        public void stopThread(){
            passThroughMode = false;
        }
        */
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        init();
        newThread = new MyThread(true);
        newThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
/*  
    private void recordAndPlay(boolean pTM) {
        short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
        int num = 0;
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        record.startRecording();
        track.play();
        while (pTM) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
            for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }
*/  
    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        else{
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }

/*
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        newThread.stop();
    }
    */

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // newThread.stopThread();
        newThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

During the first run the program runs fine, the sound at the microphone gets passed through to the speaker and the thread seems to stop when I press the return button as well, so the pass through stops when the app exits. However, if I run the app again, the pass through does not happen. Does the

```
newThread = new MyThread(true);
newThread.start();
```

start a new Thread each time the app is executed (that is, onCreate() is called),  or does it remember the state of the old Thread for some reason? How can I completely reset this app, so that every time it executes a completely new app is started?

--- EDIT ---

Alternate version without interrupts:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;  // 1024 ORIGINAL
    final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    int i= 0;
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private volatile boolean passThroughMode = true;
         /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            recordAndPlay(passThroughMode);
        }
        // */


        // /*
        MyThread(){
            super();
        }

        MyThread(boolean newPTV){
            this.passThroughMode = newPTV;
        }
        // */

        // /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            int num = 0;
            // am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            // am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            while (passThroughMode) {
            // while (!isInterrupted()) {
                num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                    lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
                track.write(lin, 0, num);
            }
            record.stop();
            track.stop();
            record.release();
            track.release();
        }
        // */

        // /*
        public void stopThread(){
            passThroughMode = false;
        }
        // */
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        init();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onCreate() called");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // newThread = new MyThread(true); // -> Moved this to onResume();
        // newThread = new MyThread();
        // newThread.start(); // -> Moved this to onResume()
        // newThread.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // newThread.stopThread();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onResume() called");
        newThread = new MyThread(true);
        newThread.start(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onPause() called");
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

     /* 
    private void recordAndPlay(boolean pTM) {
        short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
        int num = 0;
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        record.startRecording();
        track.play();
        while (pTM) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
            for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }
// */   
    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        else{
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }

     /*
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        // newThread.stop();
        newThread.stopThread();
    }
    // */

    // /*
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // newThread.interrupt();
         Log.d("MYLOG", "onDestroy() called");
    }
    // */
}
```

---EDIT 2---

```
08-20 20:57:58.266: D/MYLOG(21936): onResume() called
08-20 20:57:58.266: W/dalvikvm(21936): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416f5700)
08-20 20:57:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(21936): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-897
08-20 20:57:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(21936): java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
08-20 20:57:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(21936):    at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:517)
08-20 20:57:58.266: E/AndroidRuntime(21936):    at com.example.mypassthrough.MainActivity$MyThread.run(MainActivity.java:54)
08-20 20:57:58.286: D/MYLOG(21936): onPause() called
08-20 20:57:58.366: D/MYLOG(21936): onDestroy() called
```

Comment: Threads don't run twice. Your question doesn't begin to make sense.

Comment: then how do I pause and resume it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no state persistence of `Thread` objects across `Activity` instances. **However**, you made a mistake in assuming that each time you run the app you get a new Activity. Activities are persisted until the Android OS decides to remove them. Only then a new instance is created once you enter the app again - otherwise, **you get the same Activity as before, and `onCreate()` is not called again in this case**.

In other words, you should use `onResume()` and `onPause()` for init/deinit instead. Please check out the [lifecycle page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more details.

**EDIT:** another problem is that you're using `interrupt()` to control the thread's flow. This is not always a good idea, since `interrupt()` has [several side effects and may not even set the interrupt status to `true` depending on what's going with the thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29). You should use a "shouldStop" field instead, since then the semantics are set by you.

Note that this "shouldStop" field should be a **field**, passing it as an argument won't work. You should have something like this in `MyThread`:

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
        short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
        int num = 0;
        record.startRecording();
        track.play();
        while (passThroughMode) {
            num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
            for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
            track.write(lin, 0, num);
        }
    }
```

and, in `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    newThread.stopThread();
}
```

If the thread still doesn't stop, then a call is blocking it, which is typical for I/O operations.

**EDIT 2:** yet another problem is that you don't `stop()` and `release()` your `AudioTrack` and `AudioRecord` while the player thread is shut down (after the `while` loop). *A rule of thumb when using something related to I/O is that it's often attached to "native" resources, which need explicit "manual" release (and sometimes allocation). You should always check the class APIs for this in those cases.*

**EDIT 3:** ...and the `MyThread` instance, as well as all your other resources, should be initialized **completely** in `onResume()`, that includes creating fresh instances there, **not** in on `onCreate()`.

Comment: Doesn't the call to onDestroy() imply that the activity terminated? And onCreate() is called the next time I restart my activity so shouldn't a new thread be started?

Comment: I had tested the code I shared here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325654/basics-of-android-activity-life-cycle-functions

Comment: from this I saw that onDestroy() is called when I press the return button when my activity is in the foreground, and onCreate() is called the next time I run it again. I thought the same would apply here as well, or doesn't it?

Comment: @user13267 : It does, but are you sure `onCreate()` gets called each time you go back to the app? Do you see this in LogCat?

Comment: Yes I have. In fact i am doing it right now. when I press return key, onPause() -> onStop() ->onDestroy() and when i go to menu and run the same app again, onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()

Comment: @user13267 : that's unusual, I wonder what your test setup is. Regardless, I've edited the question with another problem I noticed. You should still move the thread init/deinit to `onResume()`/`onPause()`.

Comment: I am sorry I meant that flow of output for the code that I had pasted the link to in the comments. If I add Log.d() to the onCreate () of this particular code, it is not shown on the Logcat, however, the onen in onDestroy () is shown. So it seems onCreate() is not called here after all. But then again, how is the Thread running in the first place?

Comment: I had another version of this code where I use a boolean variable `passThroughMode` to determine if the infinite loop inside the `recordandplay()` should end. But even when the value of this variable is set to false, the loop did not end, probably because once the thread i started, I was not able to send the updated value of the `passThroughMode` boolean to the `recordandplay()` function.

Comment: I pasted my alternate version without the interrupts to the question.

Comment: @user13267 : I've noticed that and wondered why did you comment it out. Looking at the code, I suspect you were calling `Thread.stop()` instead of `MyThread.stopThread()`. Could you make the suggested changes in the code, and update the question with the current version of your code, and the problems you still have?

Comment: Actually I am not using the stop() method, as it said it was deprecated, that's why they are in comments. And when I had tested them they didn't work either. that was the reason I started looking for alternate methods

Comment: @user13267 : the alternative variant won't work. See the edited answer.

Comment: In my updated code I have used newThread.stopThread(). The stop() that is commented out isn't used. Currently the problem is that when the program is run, the passthrough happens as expected, but when I press the back button, it doesn't stop.

Comment: Doing what you suggested causes the passthrough to stop once I press the back button, but if I run the app again, then  the pass through doesn't restart.

Comment: @user13267 : I know, that's why I said this won't work. Please read the updated answer carefully, try out the changes suggested, and update your question if you still have any problems.

Comment: That was the whole problem actually. It made me think the Thread somehow remembered it's previous state.

Comment: I have replaced my second code with the latest updates. I brought the code from the `recordAndPlay()` function directly to the `run()` function.

Comment: this makes the passthrough stop when I press the return button, but it doesn't start again if I go to the menu and restart the app.

Comment: @user13267 : did you move the init and deinit code to `onResume()` and `onPause()`, like I told you multiple times? If so, please edit your question with the current version of the code.

Comment: I have added `onResume()` and `onPause()` and updated my second code. I moves the `newThread.start()` from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`. But the issue is still same. The passthrough happens at the beginning and stops when I press the return button, but it doesn't restart when I start the app again from the menu

Comment: should the stop() and release() be added in the onStop() as well?

Comment: @user13267 : no, as explicitly mentioned in the answer, it should happen after the `while` loop is complete, so in the `run()` method.

Comment: Wow this seems to make progress. Thank you so so so much. However this did create another problem. If I press the home button, loose focus to the app and go to the phone's desktop, but then go back to the menu and click on the app again, it tells me `Unfortunately, app has stopped`.  Is there anyway this could be fixed as well?

Comment: I added the logcat output as well, if that can be of any help. The ones called D/MYLOG were the ones generated by me using Log.d() .

Comment: @user13267 : see the edit. The exception tells you that the thread has been already started once - and this is true. Move the `new MyThread()` from `onCreate()` to `onResume()`.

Comment: I moved `newThread = new MyThread(true);` to onResume() and I have updated by code as well. But I am still getting the same error

Comment: @user13267 : no, it's a different exception. Like I said originally, you should move *all* your initialization code to `onResume`. You still have `init()` in `onCreate()`. Right now, when you resume, you're operating on the "old" instances of `Audio*`, which have been deinitialized.

Comment: I moved the `init()` function to `onResume()` and now it's working as I had wanted it to

Comment: You are definitely one of the greatest people I have ever met. thank you so so so so so much for you kind help, diligence and patience with my problem

Comment: Please, if you don't mind, just one more thing; I still don't understand how you knew that not calling `stop()` and `release()` on `record` and `track` was one of my problems; especially, why did they have to be called in `run()` (which is for the thread) immediately after the infinite while loop, instead of inside onPause() or onDestroy(), one of the functions which are the direct members of the Activity class (which is where the AudioRecord and AudioTrack objects were initialized

Comment: @user13267 : heh, you're welcome. I've edited in the answer to your final question (under "EDIT 2"). Also, a constructive criticism if I may - consider slowing down ;). I'm confident that you could solve half of the issues by yourself, once given the initial pointers. And solving a problem without assistance is a stronger learning experience than being told what the answer is - so it benefits **you**.

Comment: the problem is that I have never worked with Java before (even keep getting the C and Java syntax mixed up) but need to learn Android programming as fast as possible. I have no idea how threads work (it was one of the things I couldn't understand while I was reading about the basics of Java a few weeks ago) but for this particular problem I am working on I think learning how to use threads is a must. But this discussion has helped me a lot to understand threads as well as activity and the activity lifecycle related functions. Thank you very much for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is an inner class that has and uses references to the outer class, `MainActivity`. That way second instance of the thread may run differently from the first one, even if the new thread object itself does not inhering anything from the previous instance. As @TheTerribleSwiftTomato says, your activity may persist.

Comment: Could you please give me some ideas on how I can fix this? That is, make it so that every time I run the code, it runs as "brand new"